# How does wcout work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, console, cout

I noticed a weird problem while using wcout in a console application.

After calling a certain function, the rest of the wcout calls did not work at all. i.e. the output statements did not appear on the console.

I noticed that in the function, I had used a wide character array which was never assigned.

```
WCHAR wArray[1024];
wcout<<wArray<<endl;
```

It was after this call, all the other wcout's stopped working.

So, I was just curious to know what makes wcout different from cout, and why this problem occured,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example invokes undefined behavior.

`operator<<(std::wostream&,const wchar_t*)` expects the buffer to be null terminated, and stop printing characters when it reaches the first `L'\0'` character.  If the buffer happens to contain a null character (`L'\0'`), then the code will run "correctly" (although the output is unpredictable).  If it doesn't, then `operator<<` will keep reading the memory until it encounters one.

The presence of a null terminator is not enforced by your example.  In comparison, the following would print an unspecified number of characters, most likely junk, but is well defined:

```
WCHAR wArray[1024];
wArray[1023] = L'\0';
wcout << wArray << endl;
```

Comment: Note: Just because the array was never assigned to, does not mean the array was not valid. Someone could have done a `wcscpy` to it, for example. I assumed that the declaration was just to show the type of variable in my answer. If the OP does in fact just pass an uninitialized array, then this is the correct answer. Otherwise, I believe mine is the correct answer. +1.

Comment: @Billy: I interpreted "never assigned to" as "uninitialized".  Indeed, if the array is "valid", then `.clear()` should reset the stream state.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for helping me. But, I think this was what was happening. When I hovered over wArray with the debugger, it was a stream of garbage characters that wasn't terminated.

Answer (score 5):

`wcout` may be doing some unicode validation on the output; and failing the output if validation fails. This is in part because the Windows console subsystem does not handle Unicode very well.

Check whether or not the stream has `failbit` or `badbit` set. Resetting the stream (e.g. `wcout.clear()`) should restore stream functionality.

Strictly speaking, `cout` is a `std::basic_ostream<char>` and `wcout` is a `std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>` ... and that's really about it on the differences. It's just that there are more requirements for Unicode if that Unicode is to be well formed.